# SQL: Proper JOIN Protocol

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following tables with the following attributes:

```
Op(OpNo, OpName, Date)
OpConvert(OpNo, M_OpNo, Source_ID, Date)
Source(Source_ID, Source_Name, Date)
Fleet(OpNo, S_No, Date)
```

I have the current multiple JOIN query which gives me the results that I want:

```
SELECT O.OpNo AS Op_NO, O.OpName, O.Date AS Date_Entered, C.* 
FROM Op O
LEFT OUTER JOIN OpConvert C
ON O.OpNo = C.OpNo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Source D
ON C.Source_ID = D.Source_ID
WHERE C.OpNo IS NOT NULL
```

The problem is this.  I need to join the Fleet table on the previous multiple JOIN statement to attach the relevant S_No to the multiple JOIN table.  Would I still be able to accomplish this using a LEFT OUTER JOIN or would I have to use a different JOIN statement?  Also, which table would I JOIN on?

Please note that I am only familiar with LEFT OUTER JOINS.

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, `left outer join` and `left join` are the same thing in sql server.

Comment: You could use any type of join but what exactly makes you think you need a left join?

Comment: I'm only familiar with LEFT OUTER JOIN; I'm an intern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess in your case you could use `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` (which is the same thing as `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in SQL Server.

- `INNER JOIN` means that it will only return records from other tables only if there are corresponding records (based on the join condition) in the `Fleet` table.
- `LEFT JOIN` means that it will return records from other tables even if there are no corresponding records (based on the join condition) in the `Fleet` table. All columns from `Fleet` will return NULL in this case.

As for which table to join, you should really join the table that makes more logical sense based on your data structure.

Comment: Thank you.  I know that the sequences of your script matters with joins.  I was just confused if I could JOIN on a table that was previously joined on.

Comment: To elaborate on my last comment, thank you for the detailed response.  I understand why it's all the same.  Because I use the WHERE .... IS NOT NULL clause, it is no different than using an INNER JOIN.  I was taught to use nested queries in my DB class at school to save resources.  However you can return queries faster sometimes using joins before you get done writing the nested.  So wheres the tradeoff?  Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: @JeffOrris You're welcome. Best thing you should do is to learn about execution plans and how to read them. You will be able to understand optimisation of queries much easier than.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use all tables mentioned before in your join conditions. Actually, JOINS (no matter of INNER, LEFT OUTER, RIGHT OUTER, CROSS, FULL OUTER or whatever) are left- associative, i. e. they are implicitly evaluated as if they would have been included in parentheses from the left as follows:

```
FROM ( ( ( Op O
           LEFT OUTER JOIN OpConvert C
                ON O.OpNo = C.OpNo
          ) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Source D
             ON C.Source_ID = D.Source_ID
       )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Fleet
            ON ...
     )
```

This is similar to how `+` or `-` would implicitly use parentheses, i. e.

```
2 + 3 - 4 - 5
```

is evaluated as

```
(((2 + 3) - 4) - 5)
```

By the way: If you use `C.OpNo IS NOT NULL`, then the `LEFT OUTER JOIN Source D` is treated as if it were an `INNER JOIN`, as you are explicitly removing all the "OUTER" rows.